# How to wait in Capybara when using #all

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am aware that `wait_until` was removed from Capybara for some reason. Capybara being good at waiting, it waits fine when using `find`, but when dealing with AJAX applications, there are times when I have to use the `all` method. For instance, I am dealing with a HTML table that I can sort by clicking column names. When I apply sort on a column name and then call `all(td, text: column_name)` it returns the values that were present before the sort as the `all` method doesn't wait like the `find` method does. I am currently using a bespoke helper `wait_for_ajax` to deal with such situations. I don't want to pass the extra `:wait` argument. Is there a better way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing an app then this is relatively easy because you know the test data, so you can just do something like

```
expect(page).to have_css('table tr:first-child', text 'text first in order when sorted')
```

which would wait for the first row of the table to have the text that should appear first in the sort order once sorting has occurred.

If you are screen-scraping or testing an app where you somehow don't know the test data then it becomes more difficult. When you sort a column does anything change on the page other than the order of the rows? Is there a sort indicator, sorted column header highlight, etc?  If so you may be able to wait for that, assuming it doesn't actually update until the columns are updated (if it updates as soon as it's clicked then this won't work, and is probably actually a bad UI since you can end up with data inconsistencies).  For instance, if the column header gets a class of 'sorted' you could do something like

```
expect(page).to have_css('table th td.sorted', text: 'text of the column header you sorted by')
```

which would wait for the correct header to indicate it was sorted.

If there really are no changes to anything that indicates sorting is completed then you're out of luck and you've hit one of the very few cases where something like wait_for_ajax should be used.

Note: passing the `:wait` option wouldn't help you at all in this case. This is because it's the **maximum** amount of time that will be waited for matching elements to be found, and `#all` validly matches 0 elements - it would still return immediately (without any of the count options mentioned in another answer, which as you pointed out don't help you here anyway)

Comment: Thanks Tom. The column header does get a class `.sorted` once clicked. Actually, I am already using the `wait_for_ajax` helper for such situations. I could wait for `.sorted` I suppose but given that there is pretty much no waiting required in most cases when using Capybara, adding wait as you suggested is a bit of an overkill maybe, when `wait_for_ajax` will do the job? May be it's bad practise but given that there are many instances where it becomes necessary, I find that it usually works. Saves me from dealing with waits on a case by case basis when having to use `all` on a page

Answer (score 1):

I am using this to load all the HTML contents before it triggers the event. You can call this method whenever you want to specify the wait

```
def wait_for_ajax
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
    loop do
      active = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active')
      break if active == 0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: default_wait_time is deprecated in newer versions of Capybara for default_max_wait_time.  On top of that - using timeout like this will likely lead to breaking some of Capybara drivers, since it is likely to interrupt in the middle of evaluate_script and leave the drivers communications stack in an unknown state - look at `#synchronize` in Capybara for a safer way to do this if you really need wait_for_ajax -- it's generally unnecessary 99% of the time though (the OP may have a 1% case)

Comment: Thanks, I am already using this. I wanted to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the edge cases where a `wait_for_ajax` method is actually the correct choice. Heres my implementation which does not use `Timeout` which Tom suggested can cause errors.

```
def wait_for_ajax
  start = Time.now.tv_sec
  stop = false
  until stop do
    active = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active')
    if active == 0
      stop = true
    elsif (Time.now.tv_sec - start) > Capybara.default_max_wait_time
      stop = true
      raise Exception.new("WaitForUrlError: Timed out waiting for url: #{url}")
    end
  end
end
```